# Can't insert row in table with computed column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got a Rails 3 applicaiton running on SQL Server against a legacy database with some computed columns.  When I try to save a new record, I get an error "The column "ContractPendingDays" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator

I'm not updating this column, it just seems to be one of the columns activerecord tries to write to when adding a new record into the db.

Is there some way to stop this behavior?  I even tried changing schema rb but that didn't help. (and suboptimal anyway since I'd have to do it every time I change the db.)

Is there some way to mark a column as not updatable so activerecord doesn't try to write to it?

Answer (score 1):

Found answer here:

[Prevent NULL for active record INSERT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799626/dont-try-to-specify-certain-columns-on-activerecord-generated-insert-into)

(Use attributes.delete in a before_create filter)